# Rails Configurable authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm implementing a rails application that manage some objects let's call it project.

Every project has a:

category
region
company

I have to implement an authorization mechanism that allows me to assign user permission like that:

A User can edit all the project with region ASIA and can read all the project with category Information technology.

I found multiple gems that deal with authorization.

Which is the best one for you in relation to configurability and easy to use?

Comment: IMO I like to use the Devise gem to authentication and user management, and Pundit ([link](https://github.com/varvet/pundit)) to access authorization and scope policies. With Devise you can create users models easily and attach to oAuth services like Google, Github, Facebook... Also with Pundit is easy to create access policies to each  resource in your app. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks yes reading on Internet it seems that Pundit is the best solution in terms of configurability and easy to use

Comment: I will turn my comment into a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use the [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem to authentication and user management, and Pundit  to access authorization and scope policies. With Devise you can create users models easily and attach to oAuth services like Google, Github, Facebook... Also with [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) is easy to create access policies to each resource in your app. Hope it helps!